# PHP array of objects doesn't contain right value

Tags: php, arrays

Here is a code snippet:

```
$r = [];
$currencies = ['EUR','USD'];
$items = [];
$items[]    = (object)['product_name' => 'product1'];
$items[]    = (object)['product_name' => 'product2'];
$items[]    = (object)['product_name' => 'product3'];

$i = 0;
foreach($currencies as $currency)
{
    foreach($items as $key => $item)
    {
        $items[$key]->field1 = $i++;
        $items[$key]->field2 = $i++;
    }
    print_r($items);
    $r[]    = $items;
}

print_r($r);die('end');
```

The first two print_r, inside the foreach loop displays the correct arrays with autoincrement values in the fields.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_name] => product1
            [field1] => 0
            [field2] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_name] => product2
            [field1] => 2
            [field2] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_name] => product3
            [field1] => 4
            [field2] => 5
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_name] => product1
            [field1] => 6
            [field2] => 7
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_name] => product2
            [field1] => 8
            [field2] => 9
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_name] => product3
            [field1] => 10
            [field2] => 11
        )

)
```

But the last one in the last line displays an array whith two elements where the elements are identical, $r[0] contains the same value as $r[1]

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => product1
                    [field1] => 6
                    [field2] => 7
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => product2
                    [field1] => 8
                    [field2] => 9
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => product3
                    [field1] => 10
                    [field2] => 11
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => product1
                    [field1] => 6
                    [field2] => 7
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => product2
                    [field1] => 8
                    [field2] => 9
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_name] => product3
                    [field1] => 10
                    [field2] => 11
                )

        )

)
```

Any guess with this?

Comment: I dont see the problem..? What do you expect?

Comment: There is no field=0, field=1 etc in the last array. The first element in the last array starts with field=5 which is from the second original array

Comment: I understand your problem and it is curious. But you may need to explain it more carefully in the question. I only saw what you meant by running the code myself....

Comment: The problem is that you are actually always updating the set of 3 values in the `$items` array.  So rather than having copies of the data, you are always referencing the same set of 3 items.

Comment: interestingly     `$r[]    = print_r($items,true);` works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `$items[$key]` is an **object**, and php works with objects **by reference**.

This means, that in any of your subarrays `$items[$key]` points to the same object. And if you change value in one of objects (on **second** iteration), that reflects all other objects (the ones that were created on **first** iteration). If you want to use distinct objects - it's better to `clone` them:

```
$r = [];
$currencies = ['EUR','USD'];
$items = [];
$items[]    = (object)['product_name' => 'product1'];
$items[]    = (object)['product_name' => 'product2'];
$items[]    = (object)['product_name' => 'product3'];
$i = 0;
foreach($currencies as $currency)
{
    $cloned_items = [];
    foreach($items as $key => $item)
    {
        // `clone` item so to detach it from original item
        $cloned_item = clone $item;   
        $cloned_item->field1 = $i++;
        $cloned_item->field2 = $i++;
        $cloned_items[] = $cloned_item;
    }
    print_r($cloned_items);
    $r[]    = $cloned_items;
}

print_r($r);die('end');
```

More info about [objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).